# Underscore in filenames in \textit{} imported from a python script

Tags: python

I'm trying to import the name of a result file from a python script and displaying it in the report. In the LaTeX template I have a bunch of variables defined as `${variablename}`. The python script changes this into the actual variable values. I only have problem with one variable, the filename.

The code works as long as the filename doesn't contain any underscores. 
I've tried loosing the `\texit{}` command, using `\StrSubstitute` (with `\\_`, `\bs` and `\textunderscore`) and math mode. The only thing that kinda worked was math mode, but I want it displayes as text. With math mode the file name was so long that it continued far off the page. With `\textit{}` and no underscores it splits the filename, just like I want it.

I'm at loss.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{booktabs} % professional tables
\usepackage{gensymb} % \degree and \celsius, try '$ texdoc gensymb'
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb} % mathematical symbols
\usepackage{float, longtable, graphicx}

% end of preamble, start of document

\begin{document}

 -Code irrelevant to problem-

\section{Results}\label{sec:results}
The test results are taken from the file named \textit{${RESFILEname}}

-More irrelevant code-

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps the most robust solution for filenames is to add

```
\usepackage{url}
```

Then use `\path{my_file_name}` The `url` package commands take care of special symbols, and allow the line to break. You can customise the font used, see the comments in the file.

Comment: i find it easier to read the comments in the file, but i'm "unusual".  url.sty is one of the packages i've generated tex->pdf docs for.  `$MLC/url/url.pdf` on ctan, `texdoc url` on my tl machine

Comment: David: Thanks. That worked! The actual reference doesn't work, but that's not too big of a problem. I also added
   urlcolor=black so it wouldn't stand out so much

Answer (score 7):

You can use the package `url` as stated by David Carlisle, but if you want your filenames to be printed in italic, I suggest to define a custom command with a custom font.

That is, add the following lines to your document:

```
\usepackage{url}
\def\UrlFont{\it}                         % italic shape for the used font
\DeclareUrlCommand\itfile{\urlstyle{it}}  % declare new command \itfile
```

and then replace `\textit{${RESFILEname}}` with `\itfile{${RESFILEname}}`, so to have

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{booktabs} % professional tables
\usepackage{gensymb} % \degree and \celsius, try '$ texdoc gensymb'
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb} % mathematical symbols
\usepackage{float, longtable, graphicx}

\usepackage{url}
\def\UrlFont{\it}                         % italic shape for the used font
\DeclareUrlCommand\itfile{\urlstyle{it}}  % declare new command \itfile

% end of preamble, start of document

\begin{document}

 -Code irrelevant to problem-

\section{Results}\label{sec:results}
The test results are taken from the file named \itfile{${RESFILEname}}

-More irrelevant code-

\end{document}
```